# How to set height on PDF file when linked to from HTML?

Tags: html, css, url, pdf, hyperlink

I've just created a link which when clicked will take the user to a PDF file.

However when I open the PDF document on the mobile it shows only 3/4 of the page. The rest on the page is just black.

Is there a way in the CSS I can set a default zoom on the PDF?

**HTML code:**

```
<a href="privacyStatement.pdf" class="item icon icon-accessory item-icon-right">
  Privacy Statement
  <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Doubtful if this is CSS related...more whatever you are using to view the PDF document.

Comment: The PDF woud be another document and different users may have different apps or settings to determine how they are viewed.

Comment: @Paulie_D: While you are right that some *"apps or settings ... determine how they are viewed"*, ***some*** apps honor requests for specific zoom levels and other URL modifiers. See my answer down here...  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this Adobe document:

- **[Parameters for Opening PDF Files](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf#G4.1500435)**
  (`http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf#G4.1500435`)

It describes different ways to set URL modifiers in a HTTP request.
But only Adobe PDF viewers will honor most of them.
Some may only work if the requested PDF is *'web optimized'* (a.k.a. as *'linearized'*).
Some viewers made by other vendors may support *some* of these only.

You may be able to link to a specific page within a PDF hosted on the web.
So it could open on this page instead of the title page. The `page=<pagenum>` parameter is meant for that.

For example, try if your viewer jumps from the following link to **[Page 3](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf#page=3)** of above PDF Opening Parameter reference. 
*(The previous link requests the viewer to open the destination PDF directly at page 3).*

Other parameters are useful too:

- **`#search=<wordList>`**.
  Example: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf#search="commentID"
- **`#nameddest=<destination>`**
  The PDF of course must contain such a *named destination*.
  Otherwise it will not work.
  You can create named destinations within a PDF with Acrobat (***not*** with Adobe Reader, though!):
      1. Go to the desired location in the PDF.
      1. Click *'View > Navigation Tabs > Destinations'*.
      1. Go to *'Options'*, choose *'Scan Document'*
      1. Once scan is completed, select *'New Destination'* from the *'Options'* menu; then enter the name you want.

  *Important note:* Named destinations are not the same as *bookmarks*. 
    There is no documented URL parameter which would link to a bookmark.
- **`#comment=<commentID>`**
  Specifies a comment on a given page in the PDF document. 
  Use the `#page=....` command before this on. 
  For example: `#page=1&comment=fd22-457c-84aa-2cf5bed5-452fde0e`.

### Zoom

Yes, you can also request a zoom level on a specific page:

- **`#page=3&zoom=100`**
  This would request a 100% zoom level for page 3.
- **`#page=3&view=Fit`**
  ***This is probably what you want!***
  It asks to display page 3, with its contents magnified just enough to fit the entire page within the window both horizontally and vertically. 
  If the required horizontal and vertical magnification factors are different, it uses the smaller of the two, centering the page within the window in the other dimension.

However, if it works is fully dependent on the viewer software, there is no guarantee for it to work. Good luck with that!

More details in the initially linked Adobe PDF file....